# How to set LDAP encoding in JBoss

Tags: encoding, jboss, ldap

I have java code that connects to LDAP and gets data from there, the problem is that I get wrong encoded characters, is it possible to set somewhere in JBoss config encoding for LDAP?

Comment: Can you provide some more details. Examples, code something? LDAP is UTF-8. I, at least, do not understand the problem.

Comment: yes, LDAP is UTF-8 and i need to make it ISO-8859-2, how i can do that?

Comment: LDAP is a protocol and AFIK, LDAP Version 3 uses UTF-8 to encode its strings.